# Spring data jpa Constraint Violation exception is not happening on save

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple spring-boot application, I am using spring-data-jpa. While saving the record with the same id I am expecting it to throw the exception, but it's not throwing the exception and executing the code. Although the record is not being save in DB, but the exception is also not thrown. I am expecting the below code will go to the exception block, but instead it's directly returing the responseentity with created status code.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/events")
    public Object addEvent(@RequestBody Event event,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            eventRepository.save(event);
        }catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Entity Class:

```
package com.hackerrank.github.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="EVENT")
public class Event implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1327610423837025202L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID", unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="TYPE")
    private String type;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ACTOR_ID")
    private Actor actor;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="REPO_ID")
    private Repo repo;
    @Column(name="CREATED")
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    public Event() {
    }

    public Event(Long id, String type, Actor actor, Repo repo, Timestamp createdAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.actor = actor;
        this.repo = repo;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Actor getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(Actor actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    public Repo getRepo() {
        return repo;
    }

    public void setRepo(Repo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Timestamp createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is entering inside `catch (ConstraintViolationException e) ` than returning the created status. I guess you want to add another return or throw an exception after `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block.

Comment: Why do you think that this should trigger Bean Validation? Bean Validation validates Bean Validation annotations. Save does a EntityManager.merge internally and this could do an update.

Comment: Actually it's not entering in (ConstraintViolationException e), it's direclty going to the last line and retruning created status code. After the save call, it's not saving the record but neither throwing the exception.

Comment: That's the correct behavoir

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am not talking about the bean validation, it should throw the exception while saving the record the db level validaiton is not happneing.

Comment: the how can I validate if the same event ID already exists in db or not ?

Comment: It does not. If you call repository.save Spring Data JPA will check if it's a new entity and if not it will call EntityManager.merge that if something has changed and UPDATE statement will be issued. If nothing changed nothing happens

Comment: then who to check for unique constraint? How to handle if the id already exists in table or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validation annotation in order to validate if event with id exists.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueIdValidator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD })
public @interface UniqueId {

    public String message() default "There is already event with this id!";

    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};

}

@Component
public class UniqueIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueId, Long>{

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && !eventService.isIdAlreadyInUse(value);
    }
}


@Service
public class EventService {

     @Autowired
     private EventRepository eventRepository;

     public boolean isIdAlreadyInUse(Long value) {
         return eventRepository.findById(value).isPresent();
     }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="EVENT")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id  
    ...
    @UniqueId
    ...
    private Long id;


}
```