# How to validate a pojo collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections

I have a collection of pojo objects

```java
public class Assignment {
    Date entrydate;
    Date exitdate;
    String team, 
    double allocation;
    String username,
    //getters and setters
}
```

The example values are
Object 1 :

> entrydate: "2000-01-01",
>   exitdate: "2019-03-31",
>   team: "team1",
>   allocation: 0.5
>   username: "user1"

Object 2:

> entrydate: "2000-01-01",
>   exitdate: "2019-03-31",
>   team: "team2",
>   allocation: 0.5
>   username: "user1"

Object 3:

> entrydate: "2019-04-01",
>   exitdate: "2019-07-31",
>   team: "team3",
>   allocation: 0.6
>   username: "user1"

Object 4:

> entrydate: "2019-05-01",
>   exitdate: "2019-07-31",
>   team: "team4",
>   allocation: 0.6
>   username: "user1"

My criterion is for a specified user and for a specific date period the count of total allocation should be 1 => logical explanation will be the engineer should not work more than 100% or less than 100% for a specified period.

We need a function in which we pass a collection of the above pojo objects and if it does not meet this criterion it should throw an error with proper explanation - like for this date range already allocation is over 1 for specified teams. Also this method should check for date gaps if any present -- logical explanation for this feature will be - the engineer should not be idle for a specified period

Method signature will be

```
List<String> getValidation(List<Assignment > assignments);
```

(suppose we know that all the assignments belong to a specific user --> no need to worry aboubt username for now)

How to properly implement this

Comment: How many times do you think to go to use that validation on many places? so that you might create a `custom validation annotation`

Comment: As you mentioned it's a pojo object are you at liberty to implement spring validations at controller and pojo level?

Comment: @JonathanJohx the validation will be used to validate data in GUI . So it wll be used frequently.  But can you explain how to use annotation

Comment: @Coder yeah my project is a spring boot project

Comment: @FKMN take a look my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627038/spring-data-jpa-constraint-violation-exception-is-not-happening-on-save/57628257#57628257 you just have to change the logic by adding the user info and validation itself.

Comment: @FKMN let me know if you have any specific scenarios other than that I covered in my answer

Comment: @JonathanJohx how to add dates validation with annotation. If we pass a collection of objects we need to check if there is gap of dates which is not covered in the collections starting from the joining date. Also we need to see if total allocation count is 1 for a specific date range

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to tackle it. There are existing annotations already in the `javax-validation-api` like `NotNull`, `Min`, `Max`, ...

You have simply use these annotations on your pojo variables for your case as specified below.

```
public class Assignment {
    Date entrydate;
    Date exitdate;
    String team, 
    @Min(0)
    @Max(1)
    double allocation;
    String username,
    //getters and setters
}
```

You need to instruct your controller that you will need validations on request body through `@Valid` annotation as below.

```
@PostMapping("someEndPoint")
public ResponseEntity getSomeThing(@Valid @RequestBody requestBody)
{
}
```

In the cases where you have to validate `@PathVariable` you have to use `@Validated` on the controller class itself like

```
@Api("AssignmentController")
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/admin")
public class AssignmentController {
}
```

In the case where you need custom validations on the fields which are not provided by `javax validations`, you can implement your custom validator and custom annotation for that purpose.

Let's look an example where you want to create an annotation `@ValidAllocation` which will validate your `allocation` field.

Creating custom annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, PARAMETER})
@Constraint(validatedBy = AllocationValidator.class)
public @interface ValidAssignment {
    String message() default "Assignment should be between 0 and 1";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Creating custom validator which is used by the annotation:

```
@Component
public class AllocationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidAssignment, Double> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Double value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return (value >=0 && value <=1);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidAssignment validAssignment)  {}
}
```

You Pojo will look like as specified below

```
public class Assignment {
    Date entrydate;
    Date exitdate;
    String team, 
    @ValidAllocation
    double allocation;
    String username,
    //getters and setters
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: One main doubt is how to take care of multiple entrydate and exitdate combination. for a particular entrydate and exitdate combination the engineer can be in multiple teams and total allocation count should be one , also we have different entrydate and exitdate combinations and no gap should be present starting from joining date. We need to validate the above for entire duration of the engineer in company. Suppose for example last year the engineer joined and working in two teams with 0.5 allocation but this year he is working in 4 teams with 0.25 allocation. How to take care of diff dates

Comment: You are looking to identify the validations across the list of Assignment objects with multiple usernames, entrydate and exitDate combinations?

Comment: yeah. exactly. I will pass all objects to the method to validate it

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way to do it as it falls more on the business logic implementation done at service level layer and not a simple request valiadation